# Hibernate 4.3.6 Configuration with Oracle 11g

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

I am trying to configure Hibernate 4.3.6 with Oracle 11g, but i am not able to configure...I am
    getting Null Pointer Exception while Creating the Session...i am putting all the configuration 
    and program file, kindly help me to get the root cause of the failure

```
    hibernate.cfg.xml

    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE</property>
    <property name="username">TEST</property>
    <property name="password">ORACLE</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">5</property>  
    </session-factory> 
</hibernate-configuration>

HibernateUtil.java

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        try{
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                    configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            return sessionFactory;
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
          return sessionFactory;
    }
}

FetchTest.java

public class FetchTest {
<br>
    public  static void main(String a[]){<br>
        System.out.println("*********************** Inside Main ***********************");

        <br><br>
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); 
    }
}

Output : -

*********************** Inside Main ***********************
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.naveen.org.FetchTest.main(FetchTest.java:18)

Please give your suggestions how to get ride from this.....?
```

Answer (score 2):

`NullPointerException` comes if you perform an operation on an object that is not instantiated.

So you are getting this exception while doing:

```
HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

which is nothing but:

```
sessionFactory.openSession();
```

As per the code you posted in your question the `sessionFactory` should be `null` because you created a `static` variable like this:

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

and directly accessing it using method `HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()` without calling `createSessionFactory()` anywhere in your code.